# How I can get unique data (*) from the table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can get unique data (*) from the table in rails based on the city

**ex :- my table as bellow**
id = 1 ,name = 'demo1' ,city = 'city1'

id = 2 ,name = 'demo2' ,city = 'city1'

id = 3 ,name = 'demo3' , city = 'city2'

**i need output based on unique city, means output should be**

id = 1 ,name = 'demo1' ,city = 'city1'

id = 2 ,name = 'demo2' ,city = 'city1'

Comment: I am confused because `city='city1'` is _not_ unique in your example output. There are two values with the same city. Do you mean you want to load only records were `city= 'city1'`?

Comment: consider city = Paris. i need all the data in table those city = paris. @spickermann

Comment: Then you can simply do `YourModel.where(name: 'Paris')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get all records based on the city then get once with uniq name keep in mind the id is unique as auto-generated by rails

```
Model.where(city: 'Paris').select('DISTINCT name')
```